# MacOS - mdfind : How to find identical files from a content point of view with a given file?

Tags: macos, duplicates, find, mdfind

I am looking for a way to find (one)/(multiple) files that (is)are identical to a given argument file. I would like to perform this with `mdfind` command which is really fast.

The command to apply would be for example like :

```
mdfind -options_same_content file_input.txt
```

I would like to do this research only on text files. I found on SO a lot of answers about this but it mostly based on `Linux find/diff classical commands` ...

If someone could indicate to me the flag `-options_same_content` to use with `mdfind` command, this would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can'd do this. The `mdfind` command queries the metadata database, and that doesn't have a record of what the contents of the objects are (such as a hashcode).

What you could do is use a filter to find things that are the same size as the original file, then you can manually run an `md5` or `shasum` on the content to see if they are the same.

```
mdfind "kMDItemFSSize == 137536"                                 `
```

Comment: @AlBlue .How do you produce the "137536" value in your example of `mdfind` command ?

Comment: It's the size of the file reported by `ls -l` -- it was just an example I used in this case

Comment: You can do `size=$(mdls -name kMDItemFSSize -raw file_input.txt)` then `mdfind "kMDtemFSSize == $size"`

Comment: I think that I have got rather to use `ls -s --block-size=1 input.txt` to get bytes size. Thanks

Comment: As you wish. `stat` is another option.